# Laravel Eloquent - (where) and (where or where or where)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm working on a search query for my data,
I want to get only the available rows which are those who have value 0 in `is_temp` column and if the user send me a search query i would like to search this value in other columns

this is what I have now:

```
$clients = Company::where('guid',$guid)->first()
        ->clients()
        ->where('is_temp',0)
        ->orderBy('name', $sort_order)
        ->skip($per_page*($page-1))
        ->take($per_page);

if($search_query != ""){
     $clients = $clients->orWhere('name','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
                        ->orWhere('email','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
                        ->orWhere('vat_number','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
                        ->orWhere('contact_name','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%');
}

$response = [
    'clients' => $clients->get() 
];
return response()->json($response, 200);
```

but when I use it this way I get also the rows that the field `is_temp` equal to 1
so I need to use (where) and (where or where or where...)

how do i do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to group the **orWhere** calls together. The following should do the trick:

```
if($search_query != ""){
  $clients = $clients->where(function($query) use ($search_query) {
    $query->where('name','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
          ->orWhere('email','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
          ->orWhere('vat_number','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
          ->orWhere('contact_name','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%');
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Undefined variable: search_query` - how can i pass the variable into the function?

Comment: @IlanFinkel you would set up a form that posts to (or gets) a page. You would then filter the request and storing the values in a variable like so: `$formVals = request()->validate([ ... ]);` Finally, pass the whole variable or a specific value at a given index in the array (if you only need one value, for example) as the "first" argument to your scope function ("first" when you call the function, but the scope declaration will have `$query` as the actual first parameter to hold the previous query scope, so your `$search_query` parameter would be the second or later parameter).

Answer (score 1):

Use Group for the orWhere:

```
if($search_query != ""){
$clients = Company::where('guid',$guid)->first()
    ->where('is_temp',0)
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('name','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
            ->orWhere('email','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
            ->orWhere('vat_number','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
            ->orWhere('contact_name','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
    })->orderBy('name', $sort_order)
    ->skip($per_page*($page-1))
    ->take($per_page);
}
$response = [
    'clients' => $clients->get() 
];
return response()->json($response, 200);
```